# Pagination links not working with admin prefix

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have routes set up with the `admin` prefix, the page I'm having trouble with has this path:

```
http://mydomain.com/admin/posts
```

I want this to be a paginated list of blog posts. That URL calls the `admin_index` action in my `posts` controller. Pretty simple.

At the bottom of my view I have this:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 1, 'last' => 1, 'separator' => '')); ?>
```

However, the pagination links send me to a URL that doesn't exist:

```
http://mydomain.com/posts/admin_index/page:2
```

I need it to generate a link such as:

```
http://mydomain.com/admin/posts/2
```

How can I do this? I've already tried setting my paginator options like so:

```
<?php $this->Paginator->options(array(
    'url'=> array('controller' => 'posts',
    'action' => 'index',
    'prefix' => 'admin'
))); ?>
```

But that makes a URL like so:

```
http://mydomain.com/posts/index/prefix:admin/page:2
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the section in the docs regarding prefixed routing:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Especially the part where you need to tell cake which routes you want to use in your app:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

Then your routing will work in your pagination.

Comment: Sure you are not overwriting in bootstrap etc? What you are facing is exactly the result of incorrectly set routing prefixes.